# Add to Collection from emptyView in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Can I somehow let my empty view know about my collection, so that I can potentially add to my collection from the empty view?

Is it not best practice if I do something like :

```
EmailsView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        emptyView: EmptyMealView,
        itemView : EmailView,
        itemViewOptions : function(){
            return {collection : this.collection}
        },
});
```

So I can do something like this in the empty view:

```
EmptyMealView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        events:{
          'click .sendEmail' : 'sendEmail',
        },
        sendFakeEmail: function(e){

          var myEmail = new Email({
              Date : new Date(),
              Type : 3
          });
          var that = this;
          myEmail.save(null,{
              success:function(model){
                  that.collection.add(model);
              }
          });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is perfectly fine. ItemViewOptions is created so that you could pass data from the parent view to its child views.

Answer (score 1):

The `emptyView` is actually a fully qualified child of the `collectionView`.

In backbone, an empty collection actually has a weird blank model in it, and your empty view actually gets this empty model. In addition, the empty view will get options passed in by the `itemviewOptions` method. You may need to implement `serializeData` in your empty view in order to retrieve data you pass in as options that isn't part of the model.

Comment: @Vic's answer lead me to understand this fact about the empty view, but I thought I would just add this answer here to clarify.